# Multiple Conditions, Single TV Alert

Tags: pine-script

On Trading View, in Pine, I'm wanting to send a single alert to open a trade only when multiple conditions are met using multiple *closed source* indicators. I'm told with open source it is possible and closed source it is not possible. Just want to confirm that before I go build a bridge to facilitate that.

Comment: Maybe with one indicator, but I'm not sure. See [https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/use-an-input-from-another-indicator-with-your-strategy-19584/](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/use-an-input-from-another-indicator-with-your-strategy-19584/)

Comment: You might also find more info at [https://kodify.net/tradingview/inputs/code-input-apply-indicator/](https://kodify.net/tradingview/inputs/code-input-apply-indicator/)